# Is uv_write actually asynchronous?

Tags: c, linux, asynchronous, strace, libuv

According to [tutorial for libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/guide/filesystem.html#buffers-and-streams), making subsequent calls to `uv_write` should not cause one write to block another write (my understanding was that they were supposed to occur on separate threads).
However I've run the example code under `strace` and it seems that this isn't the case. Having run similar examples using `uv_fs_write`, I can see that each call to write occurs on separate threads and don't block.

Can someone explain what the expected behaviour is for `uv_write` and if it is supposed to be different from `uv_fs_write` when the underlying stream is a file handle?

```
cat Makefile | strace ./uvtee/uvtee ~/out.txt

open("/home/james/out.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_CLOEXEC, 0644) = 11
ioctl(11, FIONBIO, [1])                 = 0
epoll_ctl(6, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 7, {EPOLLIN, {u32=7, u64=7}}) = 0
epoll_ctl(6, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 9, {EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}) = 0
epoll_ctl(6, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 0, {EPOLLIN, {u32=0, u64=0}}) = 0
epoll_wait(6, [{EPOLLIN|EPOLLHUP, {u32=0, u64=0}}], 1024, -1) = 1
brk(0xb3e000)                           = 0xb3e000
read(0, "examples=\\\n\thelloworld\\\n\tidle-ba"..., 65536) = 1965
write(1, "examples=\\\n\thelloworld\\\n\tidle-ba"..., 1965) = 1965
write(11, "examples=\\\n\thelloworld\\\n\tidle-ba"..., 1965) = 1965
```

Full code can be found [here](https://github.com/nikhilm/uvbook/blob/master/code/uvtee/main.c).

Comment: I've fixed it. Hopefully it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Are you certain the example you link to is a relevant example ? It seems to treat the file as if it was a pipe, it calls uv_pipe_open() on the file descriptor that refers to a regular file - which seems to bypass the point of your question.

Comment: Sorry yes the example uses a pipe to abstract the file handle. What I really wanted to know whether it expected that using a pipe to handle the file and calling uv_write has different behaviour to using uv_fs_write? Seems in the uv_fs_write that a thread is spawned for the write whereas uv_write makes sequential calls to write on the same thread.

Comment: If you take the documentation at face value, it says that for certain types (such as a pipe), write is not done in a separate thread (as a pipe can be integrated into the eventloop), while for a file/when using uv_fs_write, the operations takes place in a separate thread. i.e. yes, you are seeing the expected behavior. That said, the design of libuv likely does not assume that you should lie to libuv and connect a descriptor referring to a file with a pipe - the docs for uv_pipe_open()  even says "but it’s required that it represents a valid pipe.". So there's no guaranteed behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The fs operations run on thread pool. This is because there is no good and portable way to do non-blocking IO for files. Because we use a thread pool, write operations can indeed run in parallel. That's why uv_fs_write takes an offset parameter, so multiple threas can write without stepping on top of each other.

A notable exception to this is macOS, where a global lock is used to serialize uv_fs_write operations.

Now, network IO is totally different. We use an event loop (as you know) and write operations are queued, so they will be written in the order they were sent and when the underlying socket is writable.